# Should we be worried by the V1 SHUTDOWN recaptcha?

Tags: bug, data-explorer, captcha

It looks like ye old Google RECAPTCHA is being decommissioned but we still use it on data.stackexchange.com

Google decided to warn us with this "NUCLEAR HAZARD" style image.

[image]

So, dear site owners, let me direct you to [g.co/recaptcha/upgrade](https://g.co/recaptcha/upgrade).